# Using unzip, grep and cut

Tags: bash, shell, grep, unzip, cut

I'm looking at some legacy code and can't figure out what it's meant to do:

```
for date in 19960822 19960823 19960824 19960825 19960826 \
        19960827 19960828 19960829 19960830 19960831
do
   echo "copying files from date $date..."
   unzip /mnt/cdrom/$date.zip \
  `grep $date $DIR/files.eng | cut -d/ -f2` > /dev/null
done
```

What's that backslash \ doing after the **unzip** command? Why would you continue an unzip command?

Also, **cut** uses a custom flag (a forward slash /) and extracts the second column but then redirects to `/dev/null`? Why?

Note: I'm on OS X.

Comment: What is in the file `$DIR/files.eng`? It looks like this is matching other file patterns in that directory with `$date` also in their names and adding them to be unzipped as well.

Comment: Yup. For example,`19960822.zip` will be full of xml files `7576newsML.xml`, `7592newsML.xml`,... The file `$DIR/files.eng` contains strings such as `19960822/7576 newsML.xml`, `19960822/7592newsML.xml`,... per line.

Comment: (Being quite specific with the filenames here because the code is from the [CoNLL 2003 shared task](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/) - so it might be relevant to some NLP practitioners. :)

Comment: [what does backslash means at the end of line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7711745/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus The link you've added is not related to bash.

Comment: [Link (gist)](https://gist.github.com/andrejzg/7f26d32c5e6c70bcee7f) to the original script in case it might be of some use.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ahh yes you're right this is adding files to be unzipped. But why unzip **xml** files? This throws up a `caution: filename not matched: 7576newsML.xml` error if I try it out in shell. Could it be just sloppy programming? :S

Comment: please update your Q, rather than extend a diagnosis via comments. Good luck.

Comment: @knitty Possibly sloppy programming, or possibly the purpose and contents of the files.eng file changed over time. I wasn't sure what `unzip` would do when given a non-zip input.

Comment: The explanation that @Cyrus found is valid here too: the line after the backslash is an argument to the unzip command. 
The unzip command will unzip according to the specs given in files.eng.  This way the output of the cut command is used as input for the unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes can escape the end of line so the command can continue onto the next line. Your code is interpreted in this way:

```
for date in 19960822 19960823 19960824 19960825 19960826 19960827 19960828 19960829 19960830 19960831
do echo "copying files from date $date..."
   unzip /mnt/cdrom/$date.zip `grep $date $DIR/files.eng | cut -d/ -f2` > /dev/null
done
```

1. The `>/dev/null` is redirecting stdout from the unzip command, not the cut. `unzip -q` (quiet mode) I believe would do the same thing. It looks like this was a failed attempt to suppress the 'not matched' errors being thrown. Use `2>/dev/null`.
2. `grep $date $DIR/files.eng | cut -d/ -f2` is a substituted command; back ticks are deprecated in favor of the `$( )` method. It is currently representing the "list" according to unzip usage: `Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
   Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;`
3. The '/' is cut's delimiter. Its purpose here is to remove the file path so the substituted command returns only filenames. A better way to accomplish this is with xargs and basename: `grep $date $DIR/files.eng | xargs -n1 basename`
4. unzip is throwing the 'not matched' errors only because the zipped file does not contain the xml filenames found in files.eng.

Try using:

```
unzip /mnt/cdrom/${date}.zip $(grep ${date} ${DIR}/files.eng | xargs -n1 basename) 2>/dev/null
```

**EDIT**:

To clarify, as I see a number of comments about sloppy programming; it is sloppy, but not exactly incorrect syntax-wise. It's targeting specific, predetermined files to be updated. Other contents of the .zip file that do not match the list will not be extracted. Your unzip arguments are as follows:

```
$1 zipped_file="/mnt/cdrom/${date}.zip"
$2 include_list="$(grep ${date} ${DIR}/files.eng | xargs -n1 basename)"
$3 exclude_list=
```